# How to create separate project to test PHP application in IntelliJ 2016?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpunit, intellij-idea-2016

I have a project that is written in PHP with IntelliJ. I need to create a new IntelliJ project that contains only tests for the PHP application. I can't use classes from the application in the tests project. How can I add other project as a dependency for my project that contains the tests?

I have tried using IntelliJ module settings but I don't see the dependencies tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it works exactly like that in IntelliJ, but in PhpStorm 2016 you can do as follows:

Open Project view (View -> Tool Windows -> Project) and locate External libraries at the bottom:

[image: Project view]

Press F4 or right click -> Configure PHP Include Paths. You should see this window:

[image]

Press the + icon at the bottom of the window and locate the directory with the classes that you want to test. IntelliJ should add them as a library, which means all autocompletion features will include the classes, but you will be warned when you try to edit these files.

Comment: On IntelliJ 2016.1 it is File->Settings->PHP. Autocomplete now works. But when I run the test I get Fatal error: Class 'MyClass' not found

Comment: That's an issue unrelated to the IDE. You'd have to configure the autoloader of your test framework to include sources of your project.